# JavaFX Table Columns, SceneBuilder Not Populating

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I've been looking at tutorials, and I can't seem to get a table to populate.
I'm using net beans and scenebuilder too.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! been struggling for 5 hours.

Here is my code for the `Controller` class:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Table> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Table, String> countriesTab;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */

    ObservableList<Table> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Table("Canada"),
            new Table("U.S.A"),
            new Table("Mexico")
    );

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        countriesTab.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("rCountry"));
        table.setItems(data);
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the `Table`

```
class Table {
    public final SimpleStringProperty rCountry;


    Table(String country){
        this.rCountry = new SimpleStringProperty(country);
    }

    private SimpleStringProperty getRCountry(){
        return this.rCountry;

    }
}
```

Here is my main:

```
public class Assignment1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post your fxml code

Answer (score 2):

For `PropertyValueFactory` to find the property the item class (i.e. `Table` in this case) needs `public` as access modifier, not package private. The method returning the property needs to be `public` as well.

Furthermore the correct name for the method returning the property itself is `<nameOfProperty>Property` according to the conventions required for `PropertyValueFactory` to work.

Also since the actual type of the property is an implementation detail, it would be better design to use `StringProperty` as return type instead of `SimpleStringProperty`

```
public class Table {

    private final SimpleStringProperty rCountry;

    public Table(String country){
        this.rCountry = new SimpleStringProperty(country);
    }

    public StringProperty rCountryProperty() {
        return this.rCountry;
    }
}
```

In case you used these modifiers to prevent write access to the property, you can still achieve this effect by using a `ReadOnlyStringWrapper` and return a `ReadOnlyStringProperty`:

```
public class Table {

    private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper rCountry;

    public Table(String country){
        this.rCountry = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper (country);
    }

    public ReadOnlyStringProperty rCountryProperty() {
        return this.rCountry.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }
}
```

In case there is no write access to the property at all, simply using a getter for the property is enough. You do not need to use a `StringProperty` at all in this case:

```
public class Table {

    private final String rCountry;

    public Table(String country){
        this.rCountry = country;
    }

    public String getRCountry() {
        return this.rCountry;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've been struggling with this for quite some time. I've got it sorted now :)